# Rebooting Linux from script

Tags: linux

I have a backup script that gets executed daily via a cron job. It's copying from FTP servers, and attached USB harddisks, databases and etc.

At the end of the script, I want to reboot the Linux machine, so I put in the end of the script:

```
reboot
```

But typing uptime next day reveals that it didn't reboot. The cron job is executed by the root user, so I shouldn't need to put sudo or su infront of the command, afaik. So instead I tried other variants of the command, like:

```
shutdown -t 10 -r
shutdown -r now
/sbin/shutdown -t 10 -r
/sbin/shutdown -r now
/sbin/reboot
```

One attempt at a time of course, not all the above 5 lines after each other. The PC just doesn't reboot.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Is the script executable?

Comment: check out logs around the time the reboot is supposed to happen. note that the PATH variable is not sourced from the shell config for cron jobs so "shutdown" will not be found.

Comment: It's a bash script. And the cron job is called using a path (/home/username/backup.sh), but the individual commands in the script are called without paths, and they all run fine.
Only the reboot command refuses to be executed.

Comment: Also add `logger` commands inside your script (to write appropriate messages to the syslog), to check that indeed it has run. Maybe even `logger -t $0 reboot is $(which reboot)`

Comment: There is no restriction on cron or shell scripts to prevent a reboot. I just tested it on an RHEL VM with success. One very good reason for this could be that there is a previous return or error in the script, causing the script to stop before the reboot command would be processed.

Try running the script manually in the shell at a safe time. Watch for errors in the file copy tasks that stop the script prematurely. Check the error status via `echo $?` after, if the reboot doesn't function. Parse the script to validate it doesn't manually end before your reboot command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found (tested on Raspbian) that the shutdown command works as expected, but the key thing is that the calling script must not exit before the timer elapses. So I added a sleep command:

```
shutdown --reboot 1 "System rebooting in 1 minute"
sleep 90
```

Comment: That was it!!! :-) hah! Thanks a lot! 8 years later! lol

Comment: That's because the script is finished, exited and I think systemctl treat it as "to kill", so each subprocess is killed or stopped.

Answer (score 3):

Hell of a way to reboot it is to use

```
reboot -f
```

But this will reboot your machine in 3 seconds without gracefully stopping any services\apps, so you might consider another way around.

Also shutdown may not recognize the "-t" argument, taking the time argument like this instead:

```
shutdown -r 10 //reboot in 10 minutes
```

Anyways, **man shutdown** may come in handy. It does not appear that shutdown accepts anything less than minute resolution, but your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/956465/1431379
and it worked for me on Armbian.

I was even able to reboot the system via script that runs not-elevated.

> Try this command
>
> ```
> systemctl reboot -i
> ```
>
> To shutdown run this
>
> ```
> systemctl poweroff -i
> ```
>
> to hibernate, suspend, hybrid run
>
> ```
> systemctl hibernate -i
> systemctl suspend -i
> systemctl hybrid-sleep -i
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created a file my_reboot_file.sh  with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting reboot"
shutdown -r +1
sleep 180
```

Change the file permissions to enable execution mode:

```
chmod 755 my_reboot_file.sh
```

and inserted a task in crontab typing "crontab -e" and after, inserting the row:

```
30 16 * * * /home/SIGAD/testes_temporarios/jboss_restart >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score -1):

Allow reboot for user using `visudo`

```
your_username ALL= /sbin/reboot
```

In your script change `reboot` to `sudo reboot`

Comment: The script is run as root, how will this make a difference?

Comment: @terdon Wow duuude! You scared poor Alex away for good! Be more kinder bro! ;-)

Comment: @PhillHealey oh. That wasn't my intention, sorry if I did scare you 7 years ago, Alex! However, the answer is clearly wrong and will only mislead future visitors. The OP is running the script via cron as root, so i) it is already running as root so `sudo` won't help and ii) this is about allowing the `visudo` user to run `sudo reboot` without giving a password. Since `visudo` is not the user running the script, this is even less relevant to the question.

Comment: @terdon I know. I just found it kinda funny/odd that the poor guy registered made one comment, got knocked down by you and never returned in 7+ years despite being a member of at least 1 other stack forum.